# How to make Chrome stop loading Flash on selected websites?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, flash

I have an old laptop with low memory. I use Chrome in Ubuntu 11.04.

When I go to a website that has many flash files (ads), my laptop starts hanging and I can't do anything. Therefore, I want to disable loading Flash files in selected websites.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a netbook like that too. What I did was go to `Wrench` -> `Settings` -> (`Show advanced settings` ->) `Content Settings`,  and on the `Plugins` submenu, make sure `Click to enable` is set, then save.

This way, any flash that wants to load must be clicked on, saving resources. You can also add the site to a list of exceptions so that you'll never have to worry about clicking every time. Also, if you're worrying that Flash is taking up too much RAM, then click on `wrench` -> 
`view background pages`. This will give you Chrome's internal task manager, which also allows you to end both chrome processes and extensions. From here you can end the Flash extension, saving RAM quickly.

One of the great things about this tool is that if you're not using a page you can just end the process of it, and it'll free up the memory but still keep the tab open! (albeit content). This means you can suffer a mad case of [tabitis](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tabitis) with relatively little RAM usage.

You can also do a bit more by disabling all javascript (which these days runs like a hog on a terribly outdated netbook like mine) except for certain sites.

Also; if you're on linux, consider increasing the living bejeezes out of your `swap` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome consider downloading the AdBlockPlus extension. It downloads a list of filters of commonly known advertisements and blocks them from loading - considerably speeding up your web browsing. Additionally, you can specify it to never load any .swf (flash) files by creating your own filter.

Unfortunately, I am not positive it works on Ubuntu but it is worth investigating.